# steam fails to start because of missing 32bit libraries

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, steam, 32-bit

on a fresh install of steam on kubuntu 14.04 getting this

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is disabled by the user
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libXrandr.so.2
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
```

**EDIT**: after figuring out how to install the correct 32bit libraries, steam still fails to start. i think the cef-extensions thing is a red herring.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1454620878)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0306/133346:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0306/133346:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(203)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454588499)
[0306/133346:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160204122139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1454620878)
assert_20160306133344_1.dmp[19624]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20160306133344_1.dmp
/home/tomasz/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756: 19596 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
assert_20160306133344_1.dmp[19624]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20160306133344_1.dmp[19624]: response: CrashID=bp-6b6e5d50-0d39-492a-8efa-f6a352160306
assert_20160306133344_1.dmp[19624]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160306133344_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-6b6e5d50-0d39-492a-8efa-f6a352160306''
```

Comment: how did you install steam? via repo? via website?

Comment: using the dowloaded deb from the website.  `dpkg -i latest_steam.deb` (or something similiar, dont have the commandline handy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  because your are missing some file required my kubuntu to run steam.[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/490121928339832921/)

1. Install lib32z1
   `sudo apt-get install lib32z1`
2. install lib32ncurses5
   `sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5`

If the libraries are installed.Then try deleting steam.sh file and reinstalling steam

1. `sudo rm /home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh`
2. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam`

If both these solution is not working and if you are using  Nouveau driver try installing this  nvidia-352 driver `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

Comment: well i  think this is part of the solution. installing all the 32bit libraries i could find, its done by `sudo apt-get install libXXX:i386`. im pretty sure i have no unlinked libs now. checked vi `ldd (find . -name "*.so" -type f) | grep not`, but still not working

Comment: did you check the dump files

Comment: how and for what? i think they are process memory dumps, and the executeables have no debugging info.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: of course, many times, with QApt, dpkg, and apt-get

Comment: Try purging and reinstalling using aptitude it might work